# I am not able to add data in the vespa

Tags: vespa

I am not able to add data to the database even though the database is up.
I have checked it using

```
vespa-get-cluster-state
```

The error message that I got is in the image below.

[image]

Please let me know what to do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that all your nodes agree on the current time, by running NTP.

You'll probably be better off deploying on https://cloud.vespa.ai so you don't need to deal with this yourself.

Comment: The timing on all the nodes are the same, Can there be any other issue

Comment: The log message you quote "Message [details] are more than 5 seconds in the future" are certainly and definitely caused by clock disagreement.

Comment: Hi Jon, Yes the issue was because of the reason that you mentioned. System were have a time difference of 6 sec